# Use Dragon Age Origins character created before save checkpoint in new game

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I created a character using the character creator in Dragon Age Origins, but when I got to the tutorial, certain controls weren't working and I quit the game (no save checkpoints were reached). I can see the character's XML file in the Characters folder, but I can't figure out how to start a new game with this character. Since Origins is the first game in the series, it doesn't seem to have an import function as I've read the later games possess, and the `Load Game` option is greyed out because I didn't reach a checkpoint. Is it possible to use this character file to start playing the game, or do I have to use the character creator again?

Comment: Did you try to make a back up of the character you have, then create new one with the same name, and copy the XML file back into the folder? The file seems pretty easy to understand, there is nothing complicated there, and the game appears to load files based on name and folder, not some mysterious ID.